# Does Flip 3D exist in Windows 8? If so what is the key combination?

Tags: windows-8

[Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features) and [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Flip_3D#Windows_Flip_and_Flip_3D) both had a Flip 3D function accessed by <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Now the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key takes you to the home screen, so <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't seem to work.

Does it exist in Windows 8?

How do I do it (just to satisfy my desire to see something 3D)?

Comment: hope you don't mind my edit, just made it overkill in info instead of your cheeky work-around on question quality criteria ;)

Comment: Sorry @Nick, just spotted the 'useless' comment on William's answer below. No need to add it back though, I think it reads cleaner without!

Comment: and good old Gareth to the rescue even further ;)

Comment: @Gareth agree to that too.

Comment: Win+Tab switches between normal & metro applications, I think

Comment: Win+Tab works as shortcut, it flips between all open Metro apps and the Desktop (if you have opened it).

Comment: Has anyone tried calling Aero Flip directly by running C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe dwmapi #105 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flip 3D does not seem to be part of the Windows 8.

I also had a look through the local policy and can not find anyway to enable/disable. Looks like it may be gone for good.

Hitting <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> now brings the new Switcher which shows all open apps down the left hand side of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Aww what! That was **the** single useless part of Windows which I actually liked, even if I never used it, haha.

Comment: @Mehrdad - hehe... I can say the same! It looked pretty and amazing... most people who have never seen it go "wow" when shown... but... it is pretty useless in actual use compared to good old alt+tab!

Comment: I wonder if there are any statistics on how many people actually use it compared to Alt+Tab. I guess it was one of those frills that seems really cool for a while, but eventually falls to the wayside when the novelty wears off and productivity regains its importance (like themes).

Comment: @Synetech inc. - Given the amount of telemetry data that Microsoft has collected, I'm pretty sure they figured out that nobody actually used it. I'd too would love to see the numbers.

Comment: @William Hilsum: That was part of the Wow campaign they had when Windows Vista first came out, wasn't it? :D

Comment: well I've updated the answer for Win 8 RTM. Hope that's fine!

Comment: It Seems that I'm The only one who actually found/finds Aero Flip productive. You can see a lot of content while holding it down and actually need to press it twice to make the first app switch.

Answer (score 2):

There is a third-party version that does the same thing: [WinFlip](http://tokyodownstairs.blogspot.com/2007/11/winflip.html).

> WinFlip is a 'Flip 3D' function for Windows XP
>   It provides an alternate window-switcher to the standard Windows Alt-Tab. Winflip displays all open windows in a 3D stack, which the user can flick through and select using either keyboard or mouse.

[image]

Comment: I've used it before, and that software makes me want to cry. It's slow, buggy, and weird looking, but it _does_ work.

Answer (score 2):

Switcher is the replacement for Flip 3D:

http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-switcher-142967

The Aero code is being stripped out of Windows 8.

Comment: Are those for Metro apps, or normal apps?

Comment: Looks like it mostly just for metro-apps. The desktop apps show up as a single thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

As nice alternative, certain Microsoft mice, in combination with the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center (IntelliPoint), offer a feature called Instant Viewer.

[image]

See [these answers](https://superuser.com/questions/398419/is-instant-viewer-only-available-for-microsoft-mice) for possible ways to use it with other types of mice.