# Is Instant Viewer only available for Microsoft mice?

Tags: windows, mouse, intellimouse

I need to replace my discontinued mouse. I'm looking at non-Microsoft brands (like Razer), but I think the lack of [Instant Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/poland/hardware/mouseandkeyboard/docs/instant_viewer.html) might be a show-stopper for me.

Is this a Microsoft Mouse only feature?

I'm asking because I suspect it's actually a feature of Windows that's invoked with some special key-combo signal.

Comment: I doubt that it's a feature of Windows. More like a software that is installed with the mouse driver. If it's actually a feature of Windows, wouldn't it make more sense to be able to use it on all mouses? or at lease on all Microsoft mouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Switcher http://insentient.net/

Free software that allows you to do what instant viewer can. You can also config which mouse button activate it.

Just found out that Instant Viewer is a software install with the mouse driver. Good news is you can use it with any mouse. Just install IntelliPoint and config it. Here's the download link

x64: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=12772

x86: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14229

You need version 7 not 8 for it to work. Download link updated

Comment: That's neat. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: @chmod, were you able to get IntelliPoint to work with a non-Microsoft mouse? I just tried, but was unsuccessful. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Yup I just got it working. My mouse is basic logitech optical mouse

Comment: I also try with another logitech mouse but it didn't work, so I had to update the driver to microsoft driver and it works. Method of updating the driver is the same as iglvzx mentioned.

Comment: @chmod [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de "Dexpot") seems to be actively maintained, as opposed to [Switcher](http://insentient.net/ "Switcher"). I'm using it on a trial license now, and it's been great, even across multiple monitors.

Answer (score 7):

**Instant Viewer** is a feature of Microsoft's **IntelliPoint** mouse software drivers. If I remember correctly, it was possible to use non-supported hardware with IntelliPoint after a little bit of ingenuity. So, in the name of science, I decided to try the latest Intellipoint software with my generic HID-compliant USB mouse! ... Unfortunately, I was **unsuccessful** in getting IntelliPoint to recognize my mouse, but I will detail my procedure below in the case that it does in fact work for some mice or with **older versions** of IntelliPoint.

---

1. Download and install [Microsoft IntelliPoint](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/downloads).

   [image: install]
2. Open the `Microsoft Mouse` settings from the **Start** menu.

   [image: Microsoft Mouse]

   [image: not detected]
3. Go to the `Hardware` tab and **click** `Properties`.

   [image: hardware]
4. **Click** `Change Settings`.

   [image: change settigns]
5. Go to the `Driver` tab and **click** `Update Driver...`

   [image: update driver]
6. **Click** `Browse my computer for driver software`

   [image: browse]
7. **Click** `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`

   [image: pick]
8. **Uncheck** `Show compatible hardware`, scroll down to `Microsoft` and select a model with `(IntelliPoint)`.

   [image: model]
9. **Click** `Yes` if you are warned about possible incompatibility.

   [image: warning]
10. After the driver is install, **close** the window.

    [image: driver successfully updated]
11. Note: you may be prompted to **restart** the computer.

    [image: restart]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps, I wish I could split the bounty.